# example of worklight push notification doesn't work

Tags: notifications, push, ibm-mobilefirst

I just download the example of worklight push notifications and import it into my eclipse, however it doesn't work. The logcat show that `Push Service: The sender account is not recognized.Notifying javascript on unsuccessful registration`. My worklight is 5.0 and the android version of my phone is 2.3.7. Any help?

Comment: Which 5.0.x release? The samples are updated for the latest available Worklight version, which is 5.0.5.1 so make sure you are inline with the versions. Other than that, in Android 2.x you must have your device synced with a Gmail account for Push Notifications to function, make sure your device is set-up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android 2.x you must have your device synced with a Gmail account for Push Notifications to  properly function, make sure your device is set-up correctly.

If this is not issue at hand, make sure you have properly entered the GCM details into application-descriptor.xml:

**Instructions:**

- Go to GCM's web page: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html
- Click on "Google APIs Console page"
- If you have never done step 2 above, you will be asked to create a project, this project will have an ID. The ID is the "senderId" value you place in application-descriptor.xml
- Click on "Create new Server key..." / "Create new Android key"
  -The generated key is the "API key" value you placed in application-descriptor.xml

Comment: the worklight is 5.0.5,and i definitely set up one Gmail account,but it still the error

Comment: I have edited my answer with more details.

Comment: I follow the instructions and get the projectId and Api key,and have placed in application-descriptor.xml ----- <pushSender key="api key" senderId="projectid"/>",it that right? but i still get the error

Comment: I assume that by "api key and "projectid" you placed the actual values...?

Comment: <pushSender key="AIzaSyB5Du8JD1-v1hreg4ip7AoPCCfzJPT9KtA" senderId="nantiankflb"/>,do i get it right?

Comment: The senderId is supposed to be a number.

Comment: you mean the project number?the project id must start with a letter,so   it couldn't be a number.and once I change it into project number,it turns out other error:Incorrect phone registration with Google

Comment: ok,it turns out that the senderid should be project number and that my phone doesn't currently support C2DM. thank so much

Comment: C2DM is deprecated by Google (and by extension, Worklight). We support GCM only (The senderId and key values above are of GCM, as well as the method creating them...)